# Why MySQL JSON_EXTRACT do not accept the return value of JSON_SEARCH?

Tags: mysql

For example:

```
SET @key = '["a","b"]';
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@key, 'one', 'b');
```

...will return the path:

> "$[1]"

Insert this as the path in JSON_EXTRACT like:

```
SET @value = '["1","2"]';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@value, "$[1]");
```

...this will return the value:

> "2"

But if I write following:

```
SET @key = '["a","b"]';
SET @value = '["1","2"]';
SET @path = (SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@key, 'one', 'b'));
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@value, @path);
```

...this will drop an error:

> SQL Fehler (3143): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1 in '"$[1]"'.

Trimming the double quotes works, but I don't like this solution:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@value, TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM @path));
```

Is there an other way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

`JSON_PATH` returns a JSON object (a JSON string) that needs to be unquoted when used as string:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@value, JSON_UNQUOTE(@path));
```

> "2"